# Performance of multiple docker containers running in a single machine

Tags: node.js, performance, docker, docker-compose

(I'm fairly new to Docker, so if I write something incorrect or ambiguous, please be patient and don't hesitate to correct it please! Or If you can recommend nice document to refer to, I will be grateful and right away to look at it!)

Using `Docker` and `docker-compose` we can run *multiple containers* within *single machine*. Let's say we have multiple `Node.js` docker containers running behind a Nginx web server. In this picture, this service will receive pretty much of incoming requests(say, 1,000 requests per a second). If we have our `Nginx` work properly and `Nginx` acts as load balancers to distribute requests into backward `Node.js` servers, then each servers will get distributed amount of load.

For example, if there are 1,000 requests incoming and 10 `Node.js containers` running, then each `Node.js container` will receive 100 requests, which is 1/10 of total requests.

In this case, containers exist, so the burden each should take care of is 10% of the original one, but **actual physical resource is still unchanged** - all containers are running on the single machine. Which means, even if they get distributed amount of burden logically, the computing power should also be distributed as well.

In this situation, is it efficient or profitable to use Docker to maintain multiple containers environment? Does this setting help improving performance, or there is no significant difference between single-machine-single-web-server?

**EDIT)** Is this as similar question as "is it efficient to run `PM2` for my Node.js application"?

Comment: docker is no diff from other vm type system like lxc in regards to resources, 1gb of ram is one 1gb of ram. each instance will use what it needs from that 1gb unless restricted